# DotnetFX35 Winforms Embeded IE replacement

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer, .net-3.5

I have one very old application with millions loc developed using .NET FX 3.5.

The winforms embedded IE 11. But since MS is going to retire IE 11 soon. May I know is there any other browser which I can still embed into my WinForm?

I have no luck with WebView2. Doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why WebView2 does not work is related to your current environment. WebView2 requires .net Framework 4.6.2 or later.
For more detailed, you could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms#step-1---create-a-single-window-app).

Regarding the IE 11 you mentioned, how do you embed it? Do you use the WebBrowser control or something else?

According to [this official blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549), IE engine MSHTML (Trident) will continue to be supported, so I think you don’t have to worry about it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes using the **WebBrowser** control. Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can continue to use the WebBrowser control. AFAIK, there's no embed IE replacement using .net 3.5. If you want to use WebView2, you'll have to upgrade the .net framework to version 4.6.2 or later.